# I couldn't catch it, but what is wrong with this sentence?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, phrase-usage, run-on-sentences

I'm struggling with this sentence.

> With this option you can add only your company name but without
>   activating any link to your website.

I can't tell for sure, but I've got the feeling that there's a mistake or the possibility to improve the phrase but I can't catch it. I tried to check the grammar of it, but still couldn't figure out if it's correct or not.

Please have a look and let me know.

**Edit** - The idea is actually that the user is adding the company name to a company directory. But in this option they won't have to privilege to add also an active link to their website - which would make it easier for users to check out that company. Since I'm worried to make mistakes with those texts I generally try to keep it short but that sentence is a little bit tricky for me and I can't figure out how to formalize it...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you saw with my deleted answer, your sentence is open to different interpretations. Don't be afraid of using more words if it makes your text clearer. Something like this might work:

> With this option you can only enter your company name; you cannot enter an active link to your website.

Answer (score 0):

You paste too many words on the sentence. Fewer will do: 'This choice does not link to your website but shows only the company name.'